# Advice for Facebook canvas + Apple appstore

Tags: facebook, app-store

I am looking for receiving some solid advices from dev community.

Recently, I'm developing an iPhone game that utilizes Facebook friends and posts on wall. In addition, I'd like to setup a Facebook canvas page for the app users to see their scores with just their friends. The page would be closely described as a friend score board. (i.e. who's the top dog among us? kinda thing )

Both the iPhone app and the Facebook canvas page does not have in-app advertising, in-app purchase, nor virtual currency whatsoever. Just one time $0.99 purchase from Apple appstore and that's it.

What I'm wondering is if Facebook would ban my app because the app does not use Facebook credit. I know Facebook requires apps use Fb Credit from the 1st of this month, and recently, a lot of buzz says Facebook is trying to steer clear of Apple appstore by all means.

Could you share you insight on my case please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me the requirement you have is that the user has the iPhone app, not that they pay 99 cents. Whether the app was obtained during a "free giveaway" period or purchased for 99 cents doesn't matter. You are not processing purchases within the application, which is what would require Facebook credits.

Many sites have Facebook integration, but they also require additional account information to access parts of their site. Your additional "account information" would be the "app ID".

I'm certainly no expert on this, but I have been involved with Facebook credits since it was released in restricted alpha/beta. That was back when Facebook integrated a few apps into their store.

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip! If I might reiterate your point, can I sum it up as 'it seems fine to connect iPhone app with Facebook canvas app as long as no in-app purchase within iPhone app exists'?

Comment: You can't have any purchase options in the Facebook app unless you offer the purchase through Facebook credits. The iPhone app can have whatever purchase options you want. You could even put a link in the Facebook app to purchase the iPhone app. I've done this with the someecards Facebook app for over a year now.